# Reading from comma or tab delimited text file

Tags: php

I need to read the data from a file that can be either comma or tab delimited. I now that there is a function getcsv but it accepts only one possible delimiter.

Any ideas how to handle this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Starting from PHP 5.3, you can use [str_getcsv()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-getcsv.php) to read individual lines using different delimiters.

```
$someCondition = someConditionToDetermineTabOrComma();

$delimiter = $someCondition ? "," : "\t";

$fp = fopen('mydata.csv', 'r');

while ( !feof($fp) )
{
    $line = fgets($fp, 2048);

    $data = str_getcsv($line, $delimiter);

    doSomethingWithData($data);
}                              

fclose($fp);
```

Comment: I came to similar solution. I read the file and search for tab in it; if not found I assume that the delimiter is comma. Then use getscv as version of php is 5.2. Although I see some flaws in this, I can't think of anything better.

Comment: Perhaps count the tabs and commas (and other potential delimiters) on the first line, then compare them to the second line and so on. Whichever is most consistent is your likely delimiter. A two pass solution, unfortunately, but that's often the way when you have such an unknown.

Answer (score 12):

You can specify a delimiter for fgetcsv(). This is an example of reading tab-delimited files,

```
 while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, "\t")) !== FALSE) {
    ...
 }
```

Comment: Yes, but it can be also a csv file. The problem is how to tell for sure if it is csv or tab delemited.

Answer (score 6):

Here is an example that will read `mydata.txt` CSV fields

```
$tab = "\t";

$fp = fopen('mydata.txt', 'r');

while ( !feof($fp) )
{
    $line = fgets($fp, 2048);

    $data_txt = str_getcsv($line, $tab);

    //Get First Line of Data over here
    print_r($data_txt);
    exit;
}                              

fclose($fp);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$filePath = "somefile.txt";
$delimiter = "\t";

$file = new \SplFileObject($filePath);
while (!$file->eof()) {
    $line = $file->fgetcsv($delimiter);
    print_r($line);
}
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer to  make it more valuable for other users.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the function that I added to my utilities library for future use. I derived it from [NSSec's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1372285/6119225).

This solution allows you to specify whether you want to use the first line as keys for the array. I will probably add the ability to pass an array to be used for keys for the $first_line_keys parameter at some point.

```
/**
*   Converts a CSV file into an array
*   NOTE: file does NOT have to have .csv extension
*   
*   $file - path to file to convert (string)
*   $delimiter - field delimiter (string)
*   $first_line_keys - use first line as array keys (bool)
*   $line_lenght - set length to retrieve for each line (int)
*/
public static function CSVToArray($file, $delimiter = ',', $first_line_keys = true, $line_length = 2048){

    // file doesn't exist
    if( !file_exists($file) ){
        return false;
    }

    // open file
    $fp = fopen($file, 'r');

    // add each line to array
    $csv_array = array();
    while( !feof($fp) ){

        // get current line
        $line = fgets($fp, $line_length);

        // line to array
        $data = str_getcsv($line, $delimiter);

        // keys/data count mismatch
        if( isset($keys) && count($keys) != count($data) ){

            // skip to next line
            continue;

        // first line, first line should be keys
        }else if( $first_line_keys && !isset($keys) ){

            // use line data for keys
            $keys = $data;

        // first line used as keys
        }else if($first_line_keys){

            // add as associative array
            $csv_array[] = array_combine($keys, $data);

        // first line NOT used for keys
        }else{

            // add as numeric array
            $csv_array[] = $data;

        }

    }

    // close file
    fclose($fp);

    // nothing found
    if(!$csv_array){
        return array();
    }

    // return csv array
    return $csv_array;

} // CSVToArray()
```

Answer (score 0):

Read the whole file, or line by line and split it using split.

There you can include a regex with arbitrary delimiters. I have not PHP here to test a statement, but php.net -> search for split().
There you also have a comment relating to regex.

Comment: But that method would eliminate the enclosure functionality of getcsv, likely defeating the purpose of all but the simplest of csv files.

Answer (score 0):

you can try [explode](http://www.php.net/explode)

```
explode ( string $delimiter , string $string [, int $limit ] );
```

Comment: In comma separated file there can be a comma inside quotes which is not considered as a delimiter. That's why I want to use getscv, as it handles this properly.

Comment: This still is a viable solution so long as you are aware of the data you are working with. Also typically data is csv formats is double quote qualified - this prevents issues with exploding. Not worthy of a down vote imo. Also this code is very common in the wild for parsing CSV data...

Comment: This is not a valid solution