# PHP- Create a process to read in a tab-delimited file and display the results sorted by a specific column.

Tags: java, php

How to create a process in php or any other lanuage to read in a tab-delimited file and display the results sorted by a specific column with and without USing OOP Concept.
Thanks in advance...

Comment: Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1372223/reading-from-comma-or-tab-delimited-text-file) answer out, it may get you on the right track.

Answer (score 0):

I would write a shell script using awk

An example to extract certain *columns from a delimited file would be:

```
awk -F, 'BEGIN {OFS = FS} { print $1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7, $8, $9, $10, $11, $12, $13, $14, $15, $16, $17, $18, $19, $22, $23, $24, $25, $26, $27, $28, $29, $30, $35, $41}' oldFile.csv > newFile.csv
```

${number} representing the column number.  If you need do use this on another type of delimited file (such as CSV)  change the OFS variable `{OFS = ","}`