# split text into a multidimensional array php

Tags: php

I am having a hard time doing this..so I have a file with the following text

```
The Boys in the Boat    Daniel James Brown  067002581X  19.99   5   16.99   9   16.99
Harry Potter and the Cursed Child   J. K. Rowling, Jack Thorne, John Tiffany    1338099133  18.95   25  17.98       0   17.98
Just Mercy  Bryan Stevenson 0812994520  17.50   8   16.25   10  16.25
Me Before You   Jojo Moyes  0670026603  18.95   2   17.50   1   17.25
A Thousand Splendid Suns    Khaled Hosseini 1594489505  19.00   7   15.50   4   14.95
The Wright Brothers David McCullough    1476728742  21.95   3   18.95   3   18.95
```

I need to somehow use a function to read it into a 2 dimensional associative array..
I have no problem creating the array from scratch infact I have already done, that...the array should look like

```
$books = array( 
        "The Boys in the Boat" => array (
           "author" => 'Daniel James Brown',
           "isbn" => '067002581X',  
           "hardcover" => 19.99,
            "quantity" => 5,
            "softcover" => 5.99,
            "e-book" => 6.99,
        ),
"Jungle" => array (
           "author" => 'Upton Sinclair',
           "isbn" => '067002581',   
           "hardcover" => 19.99,
            "quantity" => 5,
            "softcover" => 5.99,
            "e-book" => 6.99,
        ),



     );
```

I have no idea how to create a function that would go through the file text line by line and make a 2d array...I know I have to use explode but I don't know what delimeter to use, since if I used space it wouldn't work and there are no other delimeters in the file..please help I have spent all day on this...

Comment: It looks like the fields are tab-delimited, so split on the tab character (`'\t'`).

Comment: great that makes sense....now how do I make the keys to be my own values like author, isbn etc??? thank you

Comment: Why don't you share the code you have so far and where you got stuck?

Comment: [Reading from comma or tab delimited text file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1372223/2943403)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I came up with.

Please note the comments in the code and also note that I supposed your example file was changed when posted here (tabs to spaces).

If you have a set number of spaces as separators this gets more difficult since we may have the same set of empty spaces inside a field (eg. Book name). This could make the script not run as expected. You can change `"\t"` to `"    "` (four spaces) if that is what you have, you need to test the file/string to know.

Tabs are fine, but you can't have tabs inside any text fields as well or this will fail.

Because the tabs are being changed for spaces here, I hardcoded them as `\t` in the code below.

```
<?php
# This is basically just exploding the elements 2 times
# and getting the elements in the right order

# This will hold the array with info
$finalResult = array();

# Your input text to be parsed
# I am supposing you have TABS as delimiters and the order never changes
$inputText = <<<EOF
The Boys in the Boat\tDaniel James Brown\t067002581X\t19.99\t5\t16.99\t9\t16.99
Harry Potter and the Cursed Child\tJ. K. Rowling, Jack Thorne, John Tiffany\t1338099133\t18.95\t25\t17.98\t0\t17.98
Just Mercy\tBryan Stevenson\t0812994520\t17.50\t8\t16.25\t10\t16.25
Me Before You\tJojo Moyes\t0670026603\t18.95\t2\t17.50\t1\t17.25
A Thousand Splendid Suns\tKhaled Hosseini\t1594489505\t19.00\t7\t15.50\t4\t14.95
The Wright Brothers\tDavid McCullough\t1476728742\t21.95\t3\t18.95\t3\t18.95
EOF;

# First break each line into array of lines
# If you are sure this file comes from *nix you can use \n as newline
# If you are sure this comes from Windows you can use \r\n
# Or you can use PHP_EOL but this use the current system as a basis for what to use
$textLines = explode("\n", $inputText);

# Now we go through each line getting all data
foreach($textLines as $line) {
    # Get each tab-separated field
    $expLine  = explode("\t", $line);
    # Sanity check
    if (count($expLine) < 8) {
        # The line does not have enough items, deal with error
        echo "Item " . (isset($expLine[0]) ? $expLine[0]." " : "") . "ignored because of errors\n";
        continue;
    }
    # new item
    # I have changed this a bit as it seems you have more fields to get than
    # what shows on your example (2 quantities, for hard and softcovers)
    $finalResult[$expLine[0]] = array(
        "author"      => $expLine[1],
        "isbn"        => $expLine[2],  
        "hardcover"   => $expLine[3],
        "hc-quantity" => $expLine[4],
        "softcover"   => $expLine[5],
        "sc-quantity" => $expLine[6],
        "e-book"      => $expLine[7],
    );
}

# Just show the data structure
var_dump($finalResult);

?>
```

And then the result:

```
array(6) {
  ["The Boys in the Boat"]=>
  array(7) {
    ["author"]=>
    string(18) "Daniel James Brown"
    ["isbn"]=>
    string(10) "067002581X"
    ["hardcover"]=>
    string(5) "19.99"
    ["hc-quantity"]=>
    string(1) "5"
    ["softcover"]=>
    string(5) "16.99"
    ["sc-quantity"]=>
    string(1) "9"
    ["e-book"]=>
    string(5) "16.99"
  }
  ["Harry Potter and the Cursed Child"]=>
  array(7) {
    ["author"]=>
    string(40) "J. K. Rowling, Jack Thorne, John Tiffany"
    ["isbn"]=>
    string(10) "1338099133"
    ["hardcover"]=>
    string(5) "18.95"
    ["hc-quantity"]=>
    string(2) "25"
    ["softcover"]=>
    string(5) "17.98"
    ["sc-quantity"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["e-book"]=>
    string(5) "17.98"
  }
  ["Just Mercy"]=>
  array(7) {
    ["author"]=>
    string(15) "Bryan Stevenson"
    ["isbn"]=>
    string(10) "0812994520"
    ["hardcover"]=>
    string(5) "17.50"
    ["hc-quantity"]=>
    string(1) "8"
    ["softcover"]=>
    string(5) "16.25"
    ["sc-quantity"]=>
    string(2) "10"
    ["e-book"]=>
    string(5) "16.25"
  }
  ["Me Before You"]=>
  array(7) {
    ["author"]=>
    string(10) "Jojo Moyes"
    ["isbn"]=>
    string(10) "0670026603"
    ["hardcover"]=>
    string(5) "18.95"
    ["hc-quantity"]=>
    string(1) "2"
    ["softcover"]=>
    string(5) "17.50"
    ["sc-quantity"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["e-book"]=>
    string(5) "17.25"
  }
  ["A Thousand Splendid Suns"]=>
  array(7) {
    ["author"]=>
    string(15) "Khaled Hosseini"
    ["isbn"]=>
    string(10) "1594489505"
    ["hardcover"]=>
    string(5) "19.00"
    ["hc-quantity"]=>
    string(1) "7"
    ["softcover"]=>
    string(5) "15.50"
    ["sc-quantity"]=>
    string(1) "4"
    ["e-book"]=>
    string(5) "14.95"
  }
  ["The Wright Brothers"]=>
  array(7) {
    ["author"]=>
    string(16) "David McCullough"
    ["isbn"]=>
    string(10) "1476728742"
    ["hardcover"]=>
    string(5) "21.95"
    ["hc-quantity"]=>
    string(1) "3"
    ["softcover"]=>
    string(5) "18.95"
    ["sc-quantity"]=>
    string(1) "3"
    ["e-book"]=>
    string(5) "18.95"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since between all of these are 2 or more space chars:

```
//create books array
$books = array();

//$text to array by each line
$arr = explode("\n",$text);

//explode and store each line
foreach ($arr as $line){
$arr2 = explode('  ',$line);
$books[] = array (
                  'name'=>trim($arr2[0]),
                  'author'=>trim($arr2[1]),
                  'isbn'=>trim($arr2[2]),
                  'hardcover'=>trim($arr2[3]),
                  'quantity'=>trim($arr2[4]),
                  'softcover'=>trim($arr2[5]),
                  'e_book'=>trim($arr2[6])
                 );
}

//the array that you want
print_r($books);
```

PHP allow it but I didn't use name inside array key because it has space in it. If you insist, you can change this line

```
$books[] = array (
```

to the

```
$books[$arr2[0]] = array (
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider each line is a subarray, each book name is an index, you can use preg_match to split by 2 or more space, the first item of the returned array is the book name (the index), the other is the values in the subarray. That is, you can write something like this:

```
<?php
$book_info_keys = array('author', 'isbn', 'hardcover', 'quantity', 'softcover', 'e-book');
$input_file = 'a.txt';

$result = array();
foreach (file($input_file) as $line) { // Read the file as an array
  // On each line, split items by 2 or more spaces
  $a = preg_split('/ {2,}/', $line);

  // Now we divide the line into two part: the first item is book name,
  // the rest is book info.
  $book_name = $a[0];
  $book_info = array();

  $i = 1; // $a[0] is book name, so the first info is at index 1
  foreach ($book_info_keys as $key) {
    $book_info[$key] = $a[$i++];
  }
  // Now insert the infos into the result array, with book name served as index
  $result[$book_name] = $book_info;
}

var_dump($result);
?>
```

And, remember that the code above is not written to be used in real life. **Add error checking everywhere you can, never assume that the input file is always valid** (as I had assumed in the code above). Maybe on some lines there are 8, 9, or more items, and on other ones there are only 6, 5 or less items. In these case the code above will malfunction.

Comment: For better performance, When it's possible use explode instead of preg_split and you can also ditch second foreach and add it directly.